# Doctrineで副問い合わせを使用したバルクUPDATE文について

Tags: php, symfony2, doctrine2

Doctrine2でのバルクUPDATE文についてです。
DQLで以下のSQLを書き換えることは出来るでしょうか。

以下のようなMySQLでは動くSQLをそのまま流し込んでいる処理があります。

```
$this->getConnection()->query(sprintf(
'UPDATE %s p, (SELECT c.post_id, count(*) as total FROM %s as c WHERE c.status = 1 GROUP BY c.post_id) as count_comment
SET p.comments_count = count_comment.total
WHERE p.id = count_comment.post_id'
, $postTableName, $commentTableName));
```

PostgreSQLでも動かしたいので、DQLに書き直してみようかと思ったのですが、なかなかうまくいきません。

DQLのマニュアルにsub-selectsを使えばいけるとかかれているようにも見えるのですが。

> References to related entities are only possible in the WHERE clause and using > sub-selects.

Comment: マニュアルの該当箇所。
http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#update-queries

Comment: 引用元追加。sub-selectの中で関連するエンテティの指定。http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744432/update-doctrine-with-join-table

Comment: 結局、UpdateStatement ::= UpdateClause [WhereClause]　の右方の定義を追いかけても、どこにもselectが出てこないので、マニュアルにあるsubselectをつかえるという記述自体が間違いなのではないかと考えています。
http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#statements

Answer (score 1):

> References to related entities are only possible in the WHERE clause and using sub-selects.

EBNFを読むと、FROM句の部分はもちろんのこと、SET句で指定する値もサブクエリを許容しないSimpleArithmeticExpressionになっていますね。前述の英文は「**WHERE句の中で**サブクエリを使う時だけ、関連エンティティを参照することができる」という意味合いなのでしょう。

だとすると下に書いた、サブクエリを使ったSQLもDQLで書き直すことはできないので・・・SQLを使ってはいかがですか？

[php - Doctrine Update query with a sub-query - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779623/doctrine-update-query-with-a-sub-query)

---

※以下 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/revisions/7586/9 の時に書いた回答です

sub-selectというのは恐らくこういうのですね。個人的にはこっちが「副問い合わせ」のような気がしますが。。

```
UPDATE hoge
SET foo = (SELECT count(*) FROM piyo)
```

とか

```
UPDATE hoge
SET foo = 1
WHERE bar IN (SELECT id FROM piyo)
```

MySQLのマニュアルでは Subquery と書かれています。

[MySQL :: MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual :: 13.2.10 Subquery Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subqueries.html)

`UPDATE table1, table2 SET ...` という書き方はMySQLの独自拡張なので DQL では使えないというのが、質問に引用されている JIRA や StackOverflow に書かれたコメントです。

QueryBuilder はわかりませんが、副問い合わせを使ったSQLに書き直すならこんな感じでどうでしょうか。このSQLは恐らくMySQLでもPostgreSQLでも動作します。

```
UPDATE %s p 
SET
  p.comments_count = (
    SELECT count(*) FROM %s c WHERE c.status = 1 AND c.post_id = p.id
  )
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。理解が足りず質問が整理されていませんでした。DQLとして書けるかという点にしぼり、QueryBuilderに関する記述を削除しました。

Comment: @yositani2002 どう「なかなかうまくいかない」のか具体的に書いてほしいところですが、とりあえず回答に加筆しました。また初版には書いていませんでしたが、回答の最後に書いたSQLは多分MySQL・PostgreSQLどちらでも動きます。